# How to convert a list of dictionaries into a list of each dictionary in the list's values?

Tags: python, mongodb, dictionary, list-comprehension

I am trying to produce a list of categories that I can pass to my html template to render a nav bar of all the categories. In the products collection in my mongo data base, every product has a category field. Using the code below I generate a pymongo cursor of all the categories.

```
categories = Database.DATABASE[ProductConstants.COLLECTION].find({}, {'category': True, '_id': False})

print(categories)
<pymongo.cursor.Cursor at 0x1049cc668>
```

Putting categories in a list gives me

```
categories = list(categories)

print(categories)

[{'category': 'Phones'},
 {'category': 'Phones'},
 {'category': 'Phones'},
 {'category': 'Phones'},
 {'category': 'Phones'},
 {'category': 'Soaps'}]
```

This seems to be a step in the right direction. I would like the end output for categories to simply be:

```
print(categories)

['Phones', 'Soaps'].
```

I have tried doing this:

```
categories = [category.values() for category in categories]
print(categories)

[dict_values(['Phones']),
 dict_values(['Phones']),
 dict_values(['Phones']),
 dict_values(['Phones']),
 dict_values(['Soaps'])]
```

If I could get rid of the dict_values I could potentially flatten this list using sum(categories, []) and then put that into a set() such that I don't have any duplicates. I believe this would give me the desired result but am not sure how to go about it. Perhaps I am going down the wrong route and there is a better way to go about all of this? Advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
categories = Database.DATABASE[ProductConstants.COLLECTION].find({}, {'category': True, '_id': False}).distinct('category')


print categories
```

This category list will contains the distinct number of category values.

Comment: i am using the distinct function while query to the database so it will only return distinct values so no chance of any duplicates

Comment: Thanks, I am getting the following error though: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: Interesting, I was unaware of this call provided by pymongo, thank you

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you need a set of categories:

```
categories = [{'category': 'Phones'},
 {'category': 'Phones'},
 {'category': 'Phones'},
 {'category': 'Phones'},
 {'category': 'Phones'},
 {'category': 'Soaps'}]


# use a set to eliminate the duplicate categories
c = set(d['category'] for d in categories)
print(list(c))
```

Output:

```
['Soaps', 'Phones']
```

**Update:**

```
c = {d['category'] for d in categories} # equivalent using a set comprehension
```

Comment: Why use `set(genexpr)` instead of just using a set comprehension?

Comment: Ok, I forgot about set comprehensions. I'll update the answer with this alternative.

Comment: @abarnert: I presume there might be a performance advantage with the set comprehension?

Comment: I would presume so

Comment: @quamrana Yes, almost certainly in CPython 2.6-3.7, but it's possible some other implementation might make them equivalent, and it won't be huge or anything. I did some detailed experiments with `list(…)` vs. `[…]` (about a 30% cost for large but trivial cases) around 3.3, and also figured out why Python can't legally optimize the former to the latter (which may have changed with the later `StopIteration` changes, I'd have to look…). If you're interested in those detail, create a new question. I'd just use a setcomp here because conceptually it seems clearer.